# Fill column B based on the column value of A

Tags: excel, vba

I have to fill some data on a gov website,
previously the website was using web version to fill data (html form with table)

at that time i was using google chrome console with jquery to fill data automatically
like this

```
$("td:contain('A')").next().find("input").val(18.5);
$("td:contain('B')").next().find("input").val(16.0);
$("td:contain('C')").next().find("input").val(15.5);
```

but now the website moved to MS excel

so i have to download excel file and fill data then upload the file again to website.

if the file was like this

[image]

how can i fill all cells in column B based on column A (like my JQuery code)

Comment: Unfortunately, converting code from one language to another is considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

### Update Column

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateColumn()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Test\2021\70330394\Test.xlsx"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const ColOffset As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    If lCell.Row < fCell.Row Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim cValue As Double

    For Each cCell In rg.Cells
        Select Case UCase(cCell.Value)
            Case "A": cValue = 18.5
            Case "B": cValue = 16
            Case "C": cValue = 15.5
            Case Else: cValue = 0
        End Select
        cCell.Offset(0, ColOffset).Value = cValue
    Next cCell
    
    ' When done testing, uncomment the following to save.
    'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
End Sub
```